# If the Gateaux derivative is not linear does this mean the Frechet derivative doesn't exist?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

It seems to be true as if the frechet exists then it is the same as the gateaux which would then be nonlinear (contradiction) but this seems useful yet I can't really find it anywhere and the lecturer hasn't mentioned it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't when if you are working in Euclidean spaces or normed spaces, but
anyway, Frechet differentiability at a point $x_{0}$ for a function
$f:E\rightarrow Y$, where $E\subseteq X$, means
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{\Vert f(x)-f(x_{0})-L(x-x_{0})||_{Y}}{\Vert
x-x_{0}||_{X}}=0
$$
where $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is linear and continuous. Now if $x_{0}$ is an
interior point of $E$, then taking a direction $v\in X$ with norm $\Vert
v||_{X}>0$ and $x=x_{0}+tv$, you get that
\begin{align*}
0  & =\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{\Vert f(x)-f(x_{0})-L(x-x_{0})||_{Y}%
}{\Vert x-x_{0}||_{X}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\Vert f(x_{0}+tv)-f(x_{0}%
)-L(x_{0}+tv-x_{0})||_{Y}}{\Vert x_{0}+tv-x_{0}||_{X}}\\
& =\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\Vert f(x_{0}+tv)-f(x_{0})-tL(v)||_{Y}}{|t|\Vert
v||_{X}}=\frac{1}{\Vert v||_{X}}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\left\Vert \frac
{f(x_{0}+tv)-f(x_{0})}{t}-L(v)\right\Vert ,
\end{align*}
which implies that there exists the Gateaux derivative in the direction $v$
with$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x_{0})=L(v).
$$
Since $L$ is linear, it follows that $v\mapsto\frac{\partial f}{\partial
v}(x_{0})$ has to be linear.